# tc netem possibly missing

Tags: linux, tc

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 that I want to simulate network latency on. It looks like `tc` is what I want to use, and I pulled this command from the examples from here: http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
```

If I run this command, I get this error message:

```
$ sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

I suspect that I might be missing whatever makes this command work. Searching lead me to believe that there might be kernel modules needed, but I couldn't be sure. I ran `lsmod` on the machine and it comes up empty.

So, I'm lost. How can I get my simulation working?

Answer (score 1):

To check if the `netem` module is indeed installed run:

```
modinfo sch_netem
```

You should see info about where it is installed and other details. If you get and error like "modinfo: ERROR: Module sch_netem not found." then it's probably not installed unless you just installed it and the current running kernel is different from the kernel for which you installed it - in which case just reboot and it should show up.

On some Linux distributions `netem` appears to be installed as part of the normal install (e.g. Ubuntu-20), but on others you need to install it as part of an extra package e.g. for Centos

```
sudo yum install kernel-modules-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal for a VPS image to be missing things found in a "regular" install, such as the many commands that are normally not required in such an environment. If you want something that's not there go through the normal install process.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. What is missing that I need to install, or, how can I find out? The link I found seems to be the main resource for this component but I see what it depends on.

Comment: @phasetwenty, as I don't use Ubuntu or tc I'll leave it to someone familiar with that distro to go over the install procedure.