# Is Traffic Control (tc) broken in Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, traffic-shaping, iproute

After upgrading from Fedora 16 to Fedora 17, Traffic Control no longer seems to work.

Running `# tc qdisc show` will output:

`qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priopmap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

However, if I run `# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms` or similar commands such as `# tc ... loss 2%` or `# tc ... corrupt 3%` I get the following:

**`RNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`**

Downgrading back to Fedora 16 allows me to use Traffic Control without this problem, so I'm convinced it's not a hardware issue.

This question is similar to [tc netem possibly missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/318926/tc-netem-possibly-missing) but I believe the right components were installed by checking `# yum provides */tc` and ascertaining that tc is from the package `iproute`, whose latest installation I have.

Is `netem` part of another package I must also install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fedora 17 they moved a lot of unused (in common usage I guess) modules for the kernel into the package *kernel-modules-extra*.

Install that and your problem will go away.

Comment: This fix works, but I had to reboot to get the new kernel extras to be loaded.

Comment: I am using CentOS 5.8 and I am having this same problem, but I cannot find the package kernel-modules-extra (or any variation on that name).

Comment: yes, it worked for me too but do not forget to reboot

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I am seeing the same issue after an upgrade from FC16.  the tc command is in the 'iproute' package and I believe the netem qdisc is defined there.

I've verified that I get the same response to other tc commands (besides just trying to add a netem qdisc) with e.g.:

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth1 handle 1:0 root dsmark indices 1 default_index 0
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

This seems to be documented at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823316

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't consider the possibility of it being a bug.